# Python Flask MySQL Word input

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Ok so basically I'm making a dictionary and this is my first time using flask so here's my python code

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def search():
    if request.method=='GET':
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('''SELECT English_Translation FROM wordentry2''')
        word = cur.fetchall()
        print (word)
        return render_template ('index.html', word = word)

@app.route('/word',methods = ['POST','GET'])
def word():
    if request.method=='POST':
        input1 = request.form['input1']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('''SELECT English_Translation * FROM wordentry2 WHERE English_Translation LIKE '%{}%' '''. format(input1))
        output = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template ('word.html', urduword = output [0]['urdu_word'], englishword = output [0]['English_Translation'])
```

and here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AutoComplete</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js">
    </script>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js">
    </script>
    
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Dictionary </h1>
    <form method="POST">
    <input type = "search" name= input1 id="tags" placeholder="Search.." >
    <input type="submit">
    <script>
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
        {% for word in word %}
            "{{word}}".slice(6,-7),
        {% endfor %}
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
} );
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So the first page loads fine the auto complete works too but when i submit an input i get a bunch of errors any idea why?
These are my errors after i enter a word

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad Jabir Dada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad Jabir Dada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request  
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad Jabir Dada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request       
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad Jabir Dada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:21:00] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Comment: What are your errors?

Comment: @gvee i added them

Answer (score 0):

I found my error here's the correct code for app.py my html code was fine

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def search():
    if request.method=='GET':
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('''SELECT English_Translation FROM wordentry2''')
        word = cur.fetchall()
        print (word)
        return render_template ('search.html', word = word)
    else:
        input1 = request.form['input1']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM wordentry2 WHERE English_Translation LIKE '%{}%' '''. format(input1))
        output = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template ('response.html', urduword = output [0][1], englishword = output [0][2])
```